# Basic/digest authentication not working - CI REST Server (Phil Sturgeon/Chris Kacerguis)

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, authentication

So, as the title states, I cannot get HTTP authentication to work with my CI REST server that I created using codeigniter-restserver (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver).

No matter what user/pass combo I send, I am always getting a response - which should NOT be the case here. I have tried both basic and digest authentication, used config auth source AND library auth source to no avail. I have absolutely no clue as to what's wrong and ANY help would be appreciated.

Rest.php

```
$config['rest_auth'] = 'digest';
$config['auth_source'] = '';
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234', 'hello' => 'world'];
```

Test controller

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require(APPPATH.'libraries\REST_Controller.php');
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

class LogTest extends REST_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index_get()
{
    // $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    $this->response([
        'status' => TRUE,
        'message' => "Successfully hit API"
    ], 200);
}

}
```

API Client

```
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/POSOrder/index.php/LogTest"); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 45);

    //Set authentication parameters
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin" . ":" . "123");

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    echo "<pre>";
    echo $output;
    echo "</pre>";

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);
```

And this is the output

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 17:27:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.24
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="REST API", qop="auth", nonce="5a78941dd9f83", opaque="aba3d4b49c454e1974970e7b5514b001"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 17:27:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.24
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"status":true,"message":"Successfully hit API"}
```

Like I said, I used wrong credentials, BUT I AM STILL GETTING A RESPONSE. Any help at all would be GREATLY appreciated, TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the exact same problem all morning.
I found a lot of issues on the github that looks [similar to this one](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/issues/766).

Looks like it's solved in [here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/commit/54b2b9cf0698811f9fdf3a1f833f94295ef7a955).

But updating through composer doesn't help and I don't see this code in the "master" branch either.

After trying the "clean" approach, I have decided to implement a small workaround that does the trick.

If you redefine the "response" method in your Controller class like the following:

```
public function response($data = NULL, $http_code = NULL) {
    // send response via REST server library
    parent::response($data, $http_code);

    // display the data and exit execution
    $this->output->_display();
    exit;
}
```

It actually works (at least for me).

Hope this helps.